# Dispatcher não reconhece o payload React Native Redux

Tags: react-native, redux

Ao tentar salvar um state novo no store do redux ele diz que tal variável não existe.

O dispatcher (onde ele aponta o erro):

```js
export const valorMdoisD = () =>{
    return{
        type: ALIGN_M,
        payload: wertEvl,
    }
}
```

o Mapdispatchto props

```js
AlignVLVarM : (wertEvl) => dispatch(valorMdoisD(wertEvl)),
```

Função de disparo:

```js
this.props.AlignVLVarM({...this.state})
```

quando eu tento retornar a variavel wertEvl ele da o erro :

ReferenceError: Cant find variable: wertEvl

ele aponta para a linha de codigo do dispatcher.

Eu uso a mesma estrutura em outros lugares do codigo mas aqui não funciona..

Segue trechos mais completos do codigo:

O componente principal:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, ImageBackground, Picker, Animated, Alert, Button} from "react-native";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


import {valorMdoisD,} from './actions/dispatchers'




class ModalAVL0 extends Component {



  state = {
    isModalVisible: false,
    cor: 1,
    letra: 1 ,
    numero: 1,
    wertEvl: 0,

    anpassung: 1.7,

  };



inversoCor = (wert) =>
{
    var anpassung = 1.7
    var invF = wert
    var invG = invF/anpassung
    var invH = (invG-1)/208
    var invCor = parseInt(invH, 10)


    if (invCor===0) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Rot</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }else if(invCor===1){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>Blau</Text>
      </View>
      )     
    }else if(invCor===2){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>Grün</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else {
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>Schwarz</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }
}

inversoBuch = (wert) =>
{
    var anpassung = 1.7
    var invF = wert
    var invG = invF/anpassung
    var invH = (invG-1)/208
    var invI = parseInt(invH, 10)
    var invJ = invG-(invI*208)
    var invK = (invJ-1)/8
    var invBuch = parseInt(invK,10)


    if (invBuch===0) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>A</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }else if(invBuch===1){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>B</Text>
      </View>
      )     
    }else if(invBuch===2){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>C</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===3){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>D</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===4){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>E</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===5){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>F</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===6){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>G</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===7){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>H</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===8){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>I</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===9){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>J</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===10){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>K</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===11){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>L</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===12){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>M</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===13){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>N</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===14){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>O</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===15){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>P</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===16){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>Q</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===17){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>R</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===18){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>S</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===19){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>T</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===20){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>U</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===21){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>V</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===22){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>W</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===23){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>X</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invBuch===24){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>Y</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else {
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>Z</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }

}

inversoStri = (wert) =>
{
    var anpassung = 1.7
    var invF = wert
    var invG = invF/anpassung
    var invH = (invG-1)/208
    var invI = parseInt(invH, 10)
    var invJ = invG-(invI*208)
    var invK = (invJ-1)/8
    var invL = parseInt(invK,10)
    var invM = invG-(invI*208)-(invL*8)
    var invStri = parseInt(invM,10)

    if (invStri===1) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>|</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }else if(invStri===2){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>||</Text>
      </View>
      )     
    }else if(invStri===3){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>|||</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invStri===4){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>||||</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invStri===5){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>|||||</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invStri===6){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>||||||</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else if(invStri===7){
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>|||||||</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }else {
      return(
      <View>
        <Text>||||||||</Text>
      </View>
      )

    }
}






  oqueleu = () => {
    this.setState({wertEvl: ((this.state.cor*208)+(this.state.letra*8) +this.state.numero)*this.state.anpassung})


    console.log(this.state.wertEvl)
}

  oquetem = () =>{
    this.props.AlignVLVarM({...this.state})
    console.log(this.props.wertEvl)
  }




  renderModalContent = () => (
    <View style={{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)',
    width: 375,
    height: 615,
    }}>
      <ImageBackground source={require('./modalEC.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        <Image source={require('./Rule.jpg')} style={{width: 375, height: 60}}></Image>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.oqueleu}
        style={{
            borderRadius: 2,
            backgroundColor: '#000080',
            width: 120,
            height: 45,
            marginTop: 20,
            marginBottom: 10,

            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 0,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.15,
            shadowRadius: 1,
            elevation: 2,
        }}>
            <Text style={{flex: 1, color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold',}}>
                Rechnen
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.oquetem} 
        style={{
          borderRadius: 2,
          backgroundColor: '#000080',
          width: 120,
          height: 45,
          marginTop: 20,
          marginBottom: 10,

          shadowColor: '#000',
          shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 0,
          },
          shadowOpacity: 0.15,
          shadowRadius: 1,
          elevation: 2,
      }}>
          <Text>Teste</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',}}>

          <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:'flex-start',}}>
            <Text style={{flex: 1, color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 25, textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold',}}> Aktuelle Werte ablesen </Text>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff', marginBottom: 10,}}>
              <Picker
              selectedValue={this.state.cor}
              style={{height: 40, width: 132, borderRadius: 2, fontSize: 15,}}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({cor: itemValue})}>
                  <Picker.Item label='Rot' value={1}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='Blau' value={2}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='Grün' value={3}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='Schwarz' value={4}/>
              </Picker>
            </View>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff', marginBottom: 10,}}>
              <Picker
              selectedValue={this.state.letra}
              style={{height: 40, width: 132, borderRadius: 2, fontSize: 15,}}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({letra: itemValue})}>
                  <Picker.Item label='A' value={1}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='B' value={2}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='C' value={3}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='D' value={4}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='E' value={5}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='F' value={6}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='G' value={7}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='H' value={8}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='I' value={9}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='J' value={10}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='K' value={11}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='L' value={12}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='M' value={13}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='N' value={14}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='O' value={15}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='P' value={16}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='Q' value={17}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='R' value={18}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='S' value={19}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='T' value={20}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='U' value={21}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='V' value={22}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='W' value={23}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='X' value={24}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='Y' value={25}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='Z' value={26}/>
              </Picker>
            </View>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff', marginBottom: 10,}}>
              <Picker
              selectedValue={this.state.numero}
              style={{height: 40, width: 132, borderRadius: 2, fontSize: 15,}}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({numero: itemValue})}>
                  <Picker.Item label='1' value={1}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='2' value={2}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='3' value={3}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='4' value={4}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='5' value={5}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='6' value={6}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='7' value={7}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='8' value={8}/>
              </Picker>
            </View>





            <Text style={{flex: 1, color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 25, textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold',}}> Ziel Werte </Text>

                <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff',  marginBottom: 10,}}>
                  {this.inversoCor(this.props.outro)}
                </View>

                <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff',  marginBottom: 10,}}>
                  {this.inversoBuch(this.props.outro)}
                </View>

                <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff',  marginBottom: 30,}}>
                  {this.inversoStri(this.props.outro)}
                </View>

          </View>




          <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',}}>
            <Image source={require('./VLF1.png')} style={{width: 187, height: 483}}></Image>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  )

  toggleModal = () => {
      this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
      // Alert("Hintere Skala ablesen")


  };
  componentWillMount() {
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)
    Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: 150,
      duration:9000
    }).start()
  }
  render() {
    const interpolateColor = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 150],
      outputRange: ['rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.0)', 'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.6)']
    })
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleModal} style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', width: 95, height: 200,}}>
          <Animated.View style={{backgroundColor: interpolateColor, width: 25, height: 38, borderRadius: 25, marginTop: 47, marginLeft: 5,}}></Animated.View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
            <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible} onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ isVisible: false })}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
                    {this.renderModalContent()}
                </View>
            </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    outro: state.MdoisD,
    valorRef: state.AdoisC

  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    AlignVLVarM : (wertEvl) => dispatch(valorMdoisD(wertEvl)),


  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ModalAVL0)
```

O meu atividade reducer tem mais de 1000 linhas de codigo então so vou colocar o case que é ativado nessa parte do codigo:

```
        case ALIGN_M:
            return{
                ...state,
                MdoisD: action.payload.wertEvl
            }
```

Como mencionei no inicio, eu tenho centenas de interações como essa por  todo o app, mas somente aqui deu esse erro.

Obrigado ja pela ajuda :D

Comment: Precisa colocar o exemplo mínimo só esses trechos não ajuda

Comment: Feito, mas to totalmente perdido ainda.. :/